# Create c++ NuGet package with nested include folders

Tags: c++, nested, nuget

I'm trying to package a toolkit for C++ where the include files are spread over several folders, like so:
`Includes - cen_dcm -dcmnet
                    -ofstd
                    -dcmdata`

Inside the nuspec is: `include: { ${SDK_Base}\cen_dcm\**\*.h };`

With this package deployed I get the include files in the following location:
`..\packages\DCMTK.3.42.0.0\build\native\include` including subfolders.

When I use the including the IntelliSense has no problems finding it, but if that include file includes something from a different folder it fails to find it.

So I use: `#include"dcmnet/assoc.h"` which works just fine, but when compiling `assoc.h` it reports it cannot find `osconfig.h`

That file is in the package but in the `ofstd` folder. 
Normally I'd solve that by adding additional includes, but since this is a package I don't want that.

What am I missing? I can't imagine that support for something so basic is lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. You can add {targets} to your autopkg file.

It looks like this:

```
targets {
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm";
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm\config";
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm\dcmtls";
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm\dcmdata";
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm\dcmnet";
      Includes += "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..${d_include}cen_dcm\ofstd";
   }
```

This additional include folders will show up in the  of your package.targets file.

There are more possibilities using {targets}. See http://coapp.org/reference/autopackage-ref.html